# Callback method for presentViewController

Tags: ios

I'm having trouble with presentViewController method and its last parameter.

```
[self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I'm new in objective-c syntax and can't find out what object should I pass to 'completion' parameter. (also didn't find any examples that use it)

I want to have callback method when my presented View Controller dismisses.

Thanks,

Milos

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a place for a [`block`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html).

> The completion handler is called after the viewDidAppear: method is
>   called on the presented view controller.

For operations on dismissal you could place your code in the `viewWillDisappear:` or `viewDidDisappear:` method.

Comment: Thanks, putting operations on viewDidDisappear worked like a charm!

Answer (score 17):

**Example of creating a completion block:**

```
[self presentViewController:navigationController 
                   animated:YES 
                 completion:^(){
                     //put your code here
                 }];
```

This block does not take parameters. other blocks may take parameters and you can define them like this example:

```
^(BOOL bFinished){
    //put your code here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example!
Unfortunately, it won't give me the solution like others noted, but at least I found out how to write completion blocks.

Comment: Why is this upvoted?  The answer is wrong.  The completion handler in presentViewController runs when it APPEARS, not when it DISAPPEARS as the OP requested.

Answer (score 11):

This method isn't going to give you what you want. The completion block is for when the view controller has completed *presenting*, not when it is dismissed. You'll need to use a different pattern, such as delegation, to get a callback when the controller is dismissed.

> The completion handler is called after the viewDidAppear: method is
>   called on the presented view controller.

See [presentViewController:animated:completion:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW75)

Comment: Thnaks, I tried with some form of delegation, but haven't been able to  implement it. Can you point me to some tutorial about delegation?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still reading this after all these years, I wanted to alert the user when an error happened inside a UIImagePickerController. Solution

```
if (error condition) {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^(void) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // Alert the user here, for instance with a UIAlertController
        });
    }];
}
```